# writing series of data in json file

Tags: python, json

Am working in project on writing output in json file.I found json write code in web.But,it writes only the last value.It doesn't store the previous value`

the code am using:

```
import json
data=0

for data in range(0,99):
    print(data)
    with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(data, outfile)
```

my print output is:

```
    >>> %Run data.py
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
>>>
```

my json output is:

```
9
```

json file show only 9.how can i store 0 to 10.can you guys solve my problem??
and i need to convert json file into a graphical format

Answer (score 1):

You need to first create your structure, and then dump *all* of it in one go into a json file:

```
import json
data = list(range(0, 99))  # You can just write range(99) instead of range(0, 99)

with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile)
```

And the output:

```
$ cat data.json 
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98]
```

If you don't want it as a list, pick another data structure to dump.  But you need to dump the entire data structure, not a single value at a time.

Comment: can you say how to draw graph using this json file please??

Comment: That's an entirely new question, it'd be a bad idea to write an answer to it here.  Make a proper question of it instead.